# referencing the current array element in strposa

Tags: php, arrays, search, strpos

I'm using the simple **strposa** PHP function to search html pages for text.

```
$ItemsToGet[ ] = "Alpha One";
$ItemsToGet[ ] = "Alpha Fifty"
$ItemsToGet[ ] = "FoxTrot Twelve";
$ItemsToGet[ ] = "Bravo Six";
$ItemsToGet[ ] = "Alpha Niner";

if ( strposa( $rawPage, $itemsToGet, 1 ) !== false )
    {
    //echo the current $itemsToGet aka the element that got the match from
    //$itemsToGet
    }


function strposa( $haystack, $needles = array( ), $offset = 0 ) {
$chr = array( );
foreach ( $needles as $needle )
    {
    $res = strpos( $haystack, $needle, $offset );
    if ( $res !== false )
        $chr[ $needle ] = $res;
    }
if ( empty( $chr ) )
    return false;
return min( $chr );

}
```

If **strposa** finds a match and traverses the brackets, I'd like to add the array item it is currently on, to another array..something like so..

```
$foundArray[ ] = $itemsToGet;
```

However, I'm not sure how to reference the current element. Using `current($itemsToGet)` always returns the first element. Is this even possible? Do I have to find something other then **strposa**?

Comment: can you add your expected input and output .. you question is not really clear

Comment: well the inputs are clearly listed. the $itemsToGet array in the strposa function. I've added a comment inside the match found bracket of the if statement but other then that I'm not sure how to make it any more clear.

Comment: Have you thought about using foreach and using strpos?

Comment: @Pitchinnate, I have. This seemed like the more natural method so this is why I'm asking

Comment: Is this simple html parser useful to you http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ ?

Comment: Where did you get the code for strposa? It isn't a built in php function.

Comment: From the web. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

this will return the $needle instead of the position.

```
function strposa( $haystack, $needles = array( ), $offset = 0 ) {
$chr = array( );
foreach ( $needles as $needle )
    {
    $res = strpos( $haystack, $needle, $offset );
    if ( $res !== false )
        return $needle;
    }
return false

}
```